# kafka ssl port for produce and consume

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

I have tried implementing SSL on port 9093 (self signed for learning) on kafka.

I have created 2 kafka clusters. Lets name them Cluster1 and Cluster2.
I have just ACL port 9093 opened between Cluster1 and Cluster2.

I know that SSL is an on-the-wire encryption and not encryption at rest. Now, the question is, if a producer , produces data to a topic on plaintext port 9092 on cluster 1, I should be able to consume the data on the SSL port 9093 for that topic on cluster 2 using the key ofcourse.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The fetch request and polled records should be encrypted, yes. You can use Wireshark to verify

Comment: ok..
if a producer , produces data to a topic on plaintext port 9092 on cluster 1, I should be able to consume the data on the SSL port 9093 for that topic. Cuz the data is not encrypted at rest but rather on the wire.